# Expectation of a discrete random variable that is case-defined from other discrete random variables

Tags: binomial-distribution, random-variable, expected-value, expectation-maximization

**Background**

The question arises from the following real-life situation: I buy a newspaper at 3 dollars and sell it at 6 dollars. I know the demand for news paper is a binomial random variable with $n=12$ and $p=0.7$, I want to maximise my expected profit.

**Problem**

The answer is obviously 8 because it is nearest to the expected demand for newspaper. But my question is about how this can be derived more vigorously. My attempt is as follows but I am stuck at the last step:

Let $p$ be the newspaper I purchased, and X be the demand for newspaper, then the profit is a discrete random variable with the following functional forms:

$$Y=  \begin{cases} 
      6X-3p & X<p \\
      3p & X \geq p 
   \end{cases}
$$

The answer is obtained when the expectation of Y is obtained in terms of p. Then it is a function to be maximised. But the problem now is: how can the expectation of such a random variable that depends on another random variable be obtained? I would very appreciate a proof of why a method works.

Comment: If you mean random variables $X$ and $Y$, answer is $Y$ is derived from $X$. $E(Y) = E(f(X))$

Comment: but then Y also changes when X becomes greater than or equal to p, how should this be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the the newspaper purchased. It is fixed and $0\le N \le 12$. Let $p_i$ probability of the demand for news paper being $i$, $0\le i \le 12$. It can be got by following the binomial distribution with parameters 12 and 0.7. Then

$$E(Y|N)=-3Np_0+(6-3N)p_1 + ... +[6(N-1)-3N]p_{N-1}+ 3N(p_N + ...+ p_{12})$$,